# Join multiple table and sort the result

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, merge, multiple-tables

This is the first question i post in stackoverflow. Hope that you guys can help me resolve this problem. I have been stuck for 2 days.

I have 6 tables. It's all below:

students:

```
id    name    lastname
1     John    Snow
2     Sansa   Stark
3     T-Bag   Bagwell
```

student_course:

```
id    student_id    course_id    course_start    course_end
1     1             1            2015-06-19      2015-08-20
2     2             3            2015-07-09      2015-09-15
3     3             1            2015-05-15      2015-08-22
```

payment:

```
payment_id    student_id    course_id
1             1             1
2             2             3
3             3             1
```

payment_initial:

```
payment_id    payment_due
1             2015-06-12
3             2015-05-08
```

payment_installment:

```
payment_id    payment_due    int_payment_due
2             2015-07-02     2015-07-15
```

passport_visa:

```
student_id    passport_expiry_date    visa_expiry_date
1             2015-09-10              2015-10-12
2             2015-09-12              2015-09-15
3             2015-10-11              2015-9-28
```

And the result i want is: result will be sort by date combined form 3 tables which have "**Date**" field. "**Date**" field after sorting include only date after present.
How can I make query string that bring me the result like this:

```
student_id(1)    course_id(1)                     course_start(2015-06-19)
student_id(2)    course_id(3)    payment_id(2)    payment_due(2015-07-02)
student_id(2)    course_id(3)                     course_start(2015-07-09)
student_id(2)    course_id(3)    payment_id(2)    int_payment_due(2015-07-15)
student_id(1)    course_id(1)                     course_end(2015-08-20)
student_id(3)    course_id(1)                     course_end(2015-08-22)
student_id(3)                                     passport_expiry_date(2015-09-12)
.....
```

I want to add **Name** and **Lastname** at the result but it show too long. So I just write like that.

Last result i want to get is the date field (sorted), and which event of date **will** happen (course start, course end, payment due...)

Sorry if my English grammar is bad. Please help me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I just collect all result after insert data (which has date field) into one table, and sort them in that table. That makes more insert query but easy to sort.
So I do it on that way.